# Disable mode idle while iOS app is running

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, rest, ios5

Does anybody know how to disable mode devices idle while app is running?
I wrote iOS app with webservices, but when screen saver starts, i have synchronization fall.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming by "screensaver" you mean disable the devices idle timer that turns off the screen, you can use this simple line:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;
```

Comment: I packed my question, that was it! Thanks @NSPostWhenIdle